# Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "MySql.Data"

Tags: c#, mysql

Como faço para adicionar a reference "MySql.Data"? Estou usando SharpDevelop e não Visual Studio!! [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seguintes soluções foram testadas no **SharpDevelop 5**, mas no **Visual Studio 2012/2013** é bem parecido:

### Opção 1 - Nuget

Clique-duplo em *References* e depois em *Manage Packages*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na janela que se abrir, digite o nome do pacote (no caso *MySql.Data*) na caixa de texto e clique no botão da Lupa para pesquisar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto! A sua referência está criada e o melhor: já que foi feita com Nuget, pode gerenciar atualizações para ela direto da IDE, basta clicar na *Updates* da janela exibida na segunda imagem.

### Opção 2 - Referência Direta

Clique-duplo em *References* e depois em *Add Reference*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique na terceira aba, ".NET Assembly Browser" e depois em "Browse" para abrir a caixa de seleção de arquivos do Windows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após selecionar a DLL já será possível referenciar seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Copia a biblioteca de classes `MySql.Data.dll` e manda para a pasta *Root* do seu projeto, exemplo, se você tiver no Visual Studio, será 
*Documentos/Visual Studio [versão]/Projects/SeuApp/bin/debug/*

 e coloca o arquivo lá... tenta fazer isso ai

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**:
Percebi que você está no SharpDevelop, então encontra onde ta o executável do seu projeto e coloca a assembly lá.